# Rails send email to manager based on customer zipcode going through three tables and associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to set it up where a customer enters in their contact information (Customer table) that then checks against the database (Zipcode) and sends an email to the Manager (Region). However the Customer data is split. First, last, phone, email, and org name are all stored in Customer. Shipping and Billing addresses are stored in CustomerAddress with an association of the ID to Customer Shipping_Address_ID.

Models

```
Customer
  [:billing_address, :shipping_address].each do |assocation|
    belongs_to assocation,
      class_name: CustomerAddress.to_s,
      required: false,
      dependent: :destroy
  end

Zipcode
belongs_to :region
validates :zipcode, presence: true

Region
has_many :zipcodes, dependent: :destroy
validates :name, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true

class CustomerForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  CUSTOMER_ATTRS = %w[
    first_name last_name phone email title
    business_name trade_name business_phone business_fax
    business_email business_segments
  ].freeze

  ADDRESS_ATTRS = %w[
    address1 address2 city state zip
  ].freeze

  attr_accessor(*CUSTOMER_ATTRS)
  attr_accessor(*ADDRESS_ATTRS.map { |attr| 'billing_' + attr })
  attr_accessor(*ADDRESS_ATTRS.map { |attr| 'shipping_' + attr })
  attr_accessor :confirm_email, :captcha_response, :shipping_is_billing

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :title,
:business_name, :trade_name, :business_phone, :business_fax,
:business_email, :business_segments,
presence: true

  validate :email_is_confirmed, :captcha_passes

  validates :billing_address1, :billing_city, :billing_state, :billing_zip,
presence: true

  validates :shipping_address1, :shipping_city, :shipping_state, :shipping_zip,
presence: true, unless: :shipping_is_billing

  def save
    return false unless valid?

    persist!
  end

  private

  def email_is_confirmed
    return if confirm_email.present? && email == confirm_email

    errors.add(:confirm_email, 'must equal email')
  end

  def captcha_passes
    captcha = Captcha.new
    return if captcha.valid?(captcha_response)

    errors.add(:captcha_response, 'is invalid')
  end

  def persist!
    customer = Customer.new(attrs_for_customer)
    customer.billing_address = CustomerAddress.new(attrs_for_address('billing_'))
    customer.shipping_address = CustomerAddress.new(
      attrs_for_address(shipping_is_billing ? 'billing_' : 'shipping_')
    )
    customer.save!
    CustomerMailer.registration(customer).deliver_later
    customer
  end

  def attrs_for_customer
    Hash[
      CUSTOMER_ATTRS.map { |attr| [attr, send(attr)] }
    ]
  end

  def attrs_for_address(prefix)
    Hash[
      ADDRESS_ATTRS.map { |attr| [attr, send(prefix + attr.to_s)] }
    ]
  end
end
```

So clearly CustomerAddress is pulling under app/forms instead of model but it's acting as a model.

I cannot figure out the query/method for this. I understand the connections are something like:

```
Customer.shipping_address_id = CustomerAddress.id
CustomerAddress.zip = Zipcode.zipcode
Zipcode.region_id = Region.id output Region.email
```

How do I take the CustomerAddress.zip and iterate/compare over the Zipcode model then connect the Customer data to the Region?

I've tried the following:

```
def something(customer)
 @zipcode = Zipcode.find_by(zipcode: customer.zip)
 @manager = @zipcode.try(:region)
 if @manager
   CustomerMailer.notify_manager(customer, @manager).deliver_later
 else
   CustomerMailer.notify_hq(customer).deliver_later
 end
end
```

This doesn't error out however it's not generating the email.

So I updated it further and removed out the mailer under the persist! method with email_notification(customer)

Then created:

```
def email_notification(customer)
 @region = Region.all
 @zipcode = Zipcode.find_by(zipcode: customer.shipping_address.zip)
 @manager = @zipcode.find_by(region_id: @region.ids)
 if @manager
   CustomerMailer.notify_manager(customer, @manager).deliver_later
 else
   CustomerMailer.registration(customer).deliver_later
 end
end
```

However I end up with undefined method `find_by' for # on the @manager.

I noticed that there's a data storage issue on making sure I get the actual shipping_address_id so I updated the method to:

```
def email_notification(customer)
 @region = Region.all
 @customer_address = customer.where.not(shipping_address_id: '')
 @zipcode = Zipcode.find_by(zipcode: @customer_address.zip)
 @manager = @zipcode.find_by(region_id: @region.ids)
 if @manager
  CustomerMailer.notify_manager(customer, @manager).deliver_later
 else
  CustomerMailer.registration(customer).deliver_later
 end
end
```

This results in

> undefined method `where' 
>   Specifically on the @customer_address.

Answer (score 0):

So I threw on binding.pry under every line and it finally clicked.

```
def email_notification(customer)
 if customer.shipping_address_id.presence
   @zipcode = Zipcode.find_by(zipcode: customer.shipping_address.zip)
   @manager = @zipcode.region.region_email
   if @manager.presence
     CustomerMailer.notify_manager(customer, @manager).deliver_later
   else
     CustomerMailer.registration(customer).deliver_later
   end
 end
end
```

It's actually not doing the notify_manager email but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling 'where' method against class instance. And you need do it against a collection, and in order to do that you should retrive all Customers addresses first. By the way you didn't give up any information about CustomerAddress class.

I can propose that it should be something like this:

```
@customer = Customer.find(name: 'Bob')  # you found customer
@customer_addresses = @customer.shipping_address # you got customer addresses
```

Now you can do this `@scoped_addresses = @customer_addresses.where('your query')` but in order to do that you have to change the association direction to vise versa.
Customer `has_many :shipping_adresses, class_name: CustomerAddresses`
And get a

```
@zip = @scoped_addresses.find('some criteria').shipping_zip
```

and futher you can [go](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions)

```
@manager = Region.joins(:zipcodes).where(zipcodes: {zipcode: @zip}).manager
```

P.S.
It would be great if you'll familiarize yourself with [Doctrine](https://rubyonrails.org/doctrine/#convention-over-configuration)